# OpenGL VAO and shaders not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to write a C++ application that will be render VAO and shaders. 
My code is here: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/sRWq8J) (glew and freeglut required).
That's my algorithm:

1. GLUT initialization
2. GLEW initialization
3. Shaders loading
4. Shaders attaching
5. Program linking
6. Attribute's and uniform's location getting
7. Buffers generating
8. Data buffering
9. Main loop (`display()` callback)
10. Buffers and program deleting

This algorithm is correct? Anyway, application doesn't render anything. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You mix Attribute and uniform for color, there are two distinct concept!

Comment: @j-p. why? in_Position is attribute and in_Color is uniform

Comment: Don't just post links to code. If it's an [mcve], put it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://ideone.com/dwogc7

Basically a 'uniform' is a contant. And here you want to set one color per vertex, so it has to be a vertex attribute (and setup like the position). And in your vertex shader, you need to propagate this from vertex shader to fragment shader.

```
--- ideone_sRWq8J_org.cpp   2016-06-02 11:26:53.592865904 +0200
+++ ideone_sRWq8J.cpp   2016-06-02 11:24:04.352863345 +0200
@@ -52,15 +52,18 @@
 const char *vShaderSrc = 
     "#version 330\n"
     "attribute vec3 in_Position;\n"
+    "attribute vec4 in_Color;\n"
+    "out vec4 vtx_Color;\n"
     "void main() {\n"
     "    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 1.0);\n"
+    "    vtx_Color = in_Color;\n"
     "}\n";

 const char *fShaderSrc =
     "#version 330\n"
-    "uniform vec4 in_Color;\n"
+    "in vec4 vtx_Color;\n"
     "void main() {\n"
-    "    gl_FragColor = in_Color;\n"
+    "    gl_FragColor = vtx_Color;\n"
     "}\n";

 /************************ GL identificators *****************/
@@ -72,7 +75,7 @@
 GLuint idVShader;
 GLuint idFShader;
 GLuint idAttributePosition;
-GLuint idUniformColor;
+GLuint idAttributeColor;

 /***************************** INPUT DATA ********************/
 int vertexIndices[3] = { 
@@ -201,15 +204,15 @@
     const char *positionAttributeName = "in_Position";
     idAttributePosition = (GLuint) glGetAttribLocation(idProgram, positionAttributeName);
     if (idAttributePosition == -1) {
-        string error = "Could not bind attribute ";
+        string error = "Could not bind position attribute";
         error.append(positionAttributeName);
         throw new ProgramException(error.c_str());
     }

     const char *colorAttributeName = "in_Color";
-    idUniformColor = (GLuint) glGetUniformLocation(idProgram, colorAttributeName);
-    if (idUniformColor == -1) {
-        string error = "Could not bind uniform ";
+    idAttributeColor = (GLuint) glGetAttribLocation(idProgram, colorAttributeName);
+    if (idAttributeColor == -1) {
+        string error = "Could not bind color attribute";
         error.append(colorAttributeName);
         throw new ProgramException(error.c_str());
     }
@@ -245,16 +248,16 @@
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, idVbo[1]);
     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, lengthVertexColors * sizeof(float), 
                  vertexColors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
-    glVertexAttribPointer(idUniformColor, 4,
+    glVertexAttribPointer(idAttributeColor, 4,
                           GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
-    glEnableVertexAttribArray(idAttributePosition);
+    glEnableVertexAttribArray(idAttributeColor);

     /*********************** MAIN LOOP ********************/
     glutMainLoop();

     /********************** DISABLE ***********************/
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(idAttributePosition);
-    glDisableVertexAttribArray(idUniformColor);
+    glDisableVertexAttribArray(idAttributeColor);

     glBindVertexArray(0);
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Your code works very well, but if I use these fixes in my project, I get GLSL compile error: "out qualifier in declaration of vtx_Color only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10". That's my project: [link](http://github.com/wlad031/ssu-coursework-2016) (you need src/ShaderProgramControl.cpp and src/Shader.cpp)

Comment: I've posted this question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590152/glsl-error-out-qualifier-only-valid-for-function-parameters-in-glsl-1-10)