# GLSL error: `out' qualifier only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

My shaders have in/out keywords. But I've got GLSL compile error: `'out' qualifier only valid for function parameters in GLSL 1.10`. Shaders have `#version 330` directive. Calling `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)` returns 3.30.

Here is my project: `github.com/wlad031/ssu-coursework-2016`. Input folder contains shaders. Main source files are [src/ShaderProgramControl.cpp](http://github.com/wlad031/ssu-coursework-2016/blob/master/src/ShaderProgramControl.cpp) and [src/Shader.cpp](http://github.com/wlad031/ssu-coursework-2016/blob/master/src/Shader.cpp). Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your src/FileReader.cpp you have :

```
        if (first != '#') {
            res.push_back(line);
        }
```

And this strips out the #version 330 ...

Comment: That was so stupid of me, sorry. Thank you.